# Ruby Quadratic Formula Error

Tags: ruby

I'm new to Ruby programming language. I'm trying to code the Quadratic Formula but it's giving me an error. Here's my code.

```
a, b, c = 5, 2, 1

x1 = -b + Math.sqrt(b**2 - 4 a*c) / 2 * a
x2 = -b - Math.sqrt(b**2 - 4 a*c) / 2 * a

puts x1
puts x2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*5x<sup>2</sup> + 2x + 1 = 0* only has complex solutions. You might want to use [`CMath`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.5/libdoc/cmath/rdoc/CMath.html) so you can get complex numbers from the square root of a negative. Another problem is the grouping of operands:

```
require 'cmath'

a, b, c = 5, 2, 1    
x1 = (-b + CMath.sqrt(b**2 - 4*a*c)) / (2 * a)
x2 = (-b - CMath.sqrt(b**2 - 4*a*c)) / (2 * a)
```

Answer (score 1):

The code is missing a `*` between `4` and `a*c`:

```
x1 = -b + Math.sqrt(b**2 - 4*a*c) / 2 * a
x2 = -b - Math.sqrt(b**2 - 4*a*c) / 2 * a
```

After the syntax error fix, you will get `Math::DomainError`, because the value of the expression `b**2 - 4*a*c` is -16; [`Math::sqrt`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Math.html#method-c-sqrt) does not allow negative value.

To avoid that error, you need to guard the lines:

```
d = b**2 - 4*a*c
if d >= 0:
    x1 = -b + Math.sqrt(d) / 2 * a
    x2 = -b - Math.sqrt(d) / 2 * a
    puts x1
    puts x2
else:
    puts "No solution"
```

Comment: and now it's giving me 'Numerical is out of domain error'.

Comment: The * syntax is not the issue -- it's that this particular set of coef's are complex

Comment: @joelparkerhenderson, It was ;). `b**2 - 4 a*c` <--- no `*` betwen `4` and `a*c`.

Comment: @Patrick, August's answer is another solution if you want complex number output.